# Procedure entry point gzdirect could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I tried to run the below command

> conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu

and it throws the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1062, in **call**
>           
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
>   
>         exit_code = do_call(args, p)
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
>   
>         exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 37, in execute
>   
>         install(args, parser, 'create')
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
>   
>         if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 664, in use_only_tar_bz2
>   
>         import conda_package_handling.api
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 12, in 
>   
>         from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2, 
> libarchive_enabled
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 11, in 
>       
>     import libarchive
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive__init__.py", line 1, in 
>          
>  from .entry import ArchiveEntry
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in 
>   
>         from . import ffi
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 27, in 
>   
>         libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
>   
>         return self._dlltype(name)
>         File "C:\Users\alexk\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 356, in **init**
>   
>         self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

and also a error window pops up saying:

> The procedure entry point gzdirect could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\User\\Anaconda3\Library\bin\libxml2.dll

Answer (score 3):

I am answering quite lately but I had a similar issue recently and this post was the closest to my issue (and had no answers).

The issue for me though was that I was trying to communicate with matlab from c++ code (using visual c++ in visual studio).

After searching a long time, I discovered that gzdirect came from zlib1.dll and not libxml.

What caused this issue for me was that I added the path to the matlab dlls at the end of my path environnment variable and because of that, a zlib from my system was used instead of Matlab Zlib.

All I had to do was to add the path to Matlab's DLL at the start of my path and not at the end.